# Executing WatiN integration tests for a .NET web application

Tags: integration-testing, watin, bdd, iis-express

Say I wanted to have a test-server which automatically picks up the latest build (from the build server) and executes all the integration tests in that build.

In order to execute those tests, a web-server is needed, since the tests will use WatiN to browse to my website and make assertions against it.

What are some ways to automatically set up this server?

A few I already investigated were:

- Cassini
- IIS Express (but it's a bit more complicated, since it doesn't expose a nice .NET interface, so I have to Shell out to the executable)

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I use WebDeploy and MSBuild to publish the application to test-server.
I deploy my application to a real IIS using WebDeploy. WebDeploy is easy to configure and use inside a script.

This is a small workflow:

- Run unit tests and another tasks.
- Create a Deployment Package using WebDeploy. (you can use this same package to deploy to production manually)
- Deploy the package to test-server using WebDeploy.
- Run Watin tests in the test-server.

Comment: Cool idea. The advantage of using real IIS is top-notch performance.